# Convert table into a tree JSON

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have following table (which is basically array of objects):

```
a    b    c
a1   b1   c1
a1   b2
a1
a2   b1
a3
```

```
const objects = [
    {a: a1, b: b1, c: c1},
    {a: a1, b: b2},
    {a: a1},
    {a: a2, b: b1},
    {a: a3}
]
```

which I want to convert to a JSON, which will be for example:

```
{
    a1: [
        {
             b1: [
                {c1: null}
             ]
        }, {b2: null}
    ],
    a2: [{b1: null}],
    a3: null
}
```

but I have no idea how to do this, like not even a small idea. Where should I start from?

Comment: Please provide your input in JavaScript notation.

Comment: If you truly don't know where to start, Stack Overflow really isn't for you. Questions here are expected to demonstrate a good-faith attempt at meeting the stated requirements before posting here, in accordance with our [ask] policy. The general recommendation in these types of situations is to break the problem down into smaller sub-steps and perform research on how to do that in your language of choice. Once you have an attempt at solving this problem, you can include the code of that attempt here as a [mre] along with a succinct explanation on where you're getting stuck.

Comment: btw, why `a1` in a sinlge row? after having a tree, this line would never appear.

Comment: @trincot, added the example

Comment: @NinaScholz, `a1`  you are right, but the example taken from data, which comes from an API, i just removed personal data

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you needed, but it is not the prettiest and refactoring is possible.
If I have time, I can take a deeper look and refactor it, but on a short time this is what I could think of.

```js
const objects = [{
    a: 'a1',
    b: 'b1',
    c: 'c1'
  },
  {
    a: 'a1',
    b: 'b2'
  },
  {
    a: 'a1'
  },
  {
    a: 'a2',
    b: 'b1'
  },
  {
    a: 'a3'
  }
]

function abc(obj) {
  let arr = []
  let output = {};
  let keys = Object.keys(obj)
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    let key = obj[keys[i]]
    i === keys.length - 1 ? output[key] = null : output[key] = []

  }
  arr.push(output)
  let keys2 = Object.keys(arr[0])
  for (let i = keys2.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let push = {}
    push[keys2[i]] = arr[0][keys2[i]]
    arr[0][keys2[i - 1]].push(push)
  }
  return Object.entries(arr[0])[0]
}

let finalOutput = {}

function getOutput(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const a = abc(arr[i])

    if (finalOutput[a[0]]) {
      if (a[1] != null && a[1][0] != null) {
        finalOutput[a[0]].push(a[1][0])
      }
    } else {
      finalOutput[a[0]] = a[1]
    }

  }
  console.log(finalOutput)
  return finalOutput
}
getOutput(objects)
```